# Slim api issue is not responding just after update routes.php file

Tags: php, rest, swagger, postman, slim

I am very new to Slim framework and getting very strange issue. 
I have to restart my apache after updating routes.php for seeing the effects of my changes because it stop responding but works perfectly only after rerstarting apache.

You can see the error
Chrome-
[image]

Postman-
[image]

---

Here is the content of my routes.php-

```html
<pre>
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

include_once 'Auth.php';
include_once 'common/ReuseFunctions.php';

include_once 'Controllers/CodeController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/UserController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/WebinarController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/NotificationController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/JobsController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/EventsCgController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/NewsController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/CodeContestController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/LeaderboardController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/SkillTestController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/TestController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/ReportController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/QuestionController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/WebinarHireController.php';
include_once 'Controllers/CommunityController.php';



session_start();

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Slim\Middleware\TokenAuthentication;
use RateLimiter\Middleware as RateLimiterMiddleware;

$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => false,
    ],
];

$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);


$c['session'] = function ($c) {
  return new \SlimSession\Helper;
};


$app = new Slim\App($c);

// $app = new Slim\App();


$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\Session([
  'name' => 'dummy_session',
  'autorefresh' => true,
  'lifetime' => '1 hour'
]));



$authenticator = function($request, TokenAuthentication $tokenAuth){

    $token = $tokenAuth->findToken($request);
    
    $auth = new Auth();

    $auth->getUserByToken($token);

};


$app->add(new TokenAuthentication([
    'path' =>   ['/user', '/webinar', '/notification', '/jobs', '/skill_test', '/news', '/leaderboard', '/code_contest', '/events_cg', '/test', '/candidate_report', '/question', '/webinar_hire'],
    'header' => 'Auth-Token',
    'regex' => '/(.*)/',
    'authenticator' => $authenticator
]));



$middlware = new RateLimiterMiddleware(['hourly_request_limit' => HOURLY_RATE_LIMIT,
        'minute_request_limit' => (new \SlimSession\Helper)->memType,
        'second_request_limit' => SECOND_RATE_LIMIT], unserialize(REDIS_SETTINGS));

$app->add($middlware);

// $middlware = new RateLimiterMiddleware(['hourly_request_limit' => HOURLY_RATE_LIMIT,
//         'minute_request_limit' => 15,
//         'second_request_limit' => SECOND_RATE_LIMIT], unserialize(REDIS_SETTINGS));

// $app->add($middlware);



$app->group('/user', function () {

   $this->get('/list_all_users', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      $result = UserController::list_all_users($request, $response, $args);
      $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->get('/retrieve_user_by_id', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::retrieve_user_by_id($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->get('/check_email_exists', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::check_email_exists($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/register_without_mobile', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::register_without_mobile($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/reset_password', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::reset_password($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/social_login', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::social_login($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->get('/country_list', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::country_list($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->patch('/update_user_profile', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::update_user_profile($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->get('/auto_suggest', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::auto_suggest($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/logout', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::logout($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/register', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::register($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::login($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->put('/change_password', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::change_password($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/edit_picture', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::edit_picture($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->get('/city_list', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = UserController::city_list($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

});

$app->group('/leaderboard', function () { 

    $this->get('/leaderboard_list', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = LeaderboardController::leaderboard_list($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });


     $this->get('/challenge_leaderboard', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = LeaderboardController::challenge_leaderboard($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    


});



    $this->get('/popular_skill_test', function ($request, $response, $args) {

       $result = SkillTestController::popular_skill_test($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });



});


$app->group('/notification', function () { 

    $this->post('/register_device', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::register_device($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });

    $this->post('/gcm_registration', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::gcm_registration($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });


    $this->post('/notification_settings', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::notification_settings($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });


    $this->get('/update_available', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::update_available($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });    


    $this->patch('/update_read_status', function ($request, $response, $args) {
       $result = NotificationController::update_read_status($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });  

    $this->get('/past_notifications', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::past_notifications($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });   

    $this->post('/app_feedback', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::app_feedback($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });   

    $this->get('/get_settings_list', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::get_settings_list($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });   


    $this->post('/log_data', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      
       $result = NotificationController::log_data($request, $response, $args);
       $response->write($result);
       return $response;
       // echo $result;
       // die;
    });     



});

$app->run();
 
?>

</pre>
```

Comment: FYI - Need not restart apache after making changes in PHP files. And what code you have updated after which it stop responding.

Comment: please add your routes.php code

Comment: routes.php content has been added now.

Comment: Do you have opcache enabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: yes. opcache is enabled by default in my php.ini.